# Uncaught Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be a string (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, angularjs

I am developing a webapp,and have ran into some difficulties, especially this one that I am having a hard time getting rid of, here is the code

```
this.bookSpace = function (date, spaceId) {

swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Would you like to book this space?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, Book it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
  },
  function () {
    var transform = function (data) {
      return $.param(data);
    };
    $http.post(
      {
        url:"/api/api/AdhocBooking?bookingDate="+date.DateTime+"&spaceId="+spaceId,

        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8','Authorization': 'bearer'},
        transformRequest: transform,
        data: {

          "Name": "Michael Knott"
        }
      });
    swal("Booked!",
      "Your space has been booked!",
      "success");
  })
```

Here is the response I get

> Uncaught Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be
>   a string

Thank you.

Comment: `date.DateTime` or `spaceId` is not **string**.

Comment: How do I do this @Tushar? It retrieves the date from the HTML, would i use toString or something similar?

Comment: Your `date.DateTime` is probably a Date object and you need to convert it into a string. Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp for js Date ref.

Comment: I changed date.DateTime like so  this.date = date.DateTime then put in the url as this.date.toString() and That did not work either

Comment: Can you please post the URL here after adding datetime to it? 
Also can you please try to URL encode the datetime and then append it?
If this does not work then you can try to post datetime in the post parameters or set is as part of header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to replace date.DateTime to be **encodeURIComponent(date.DateTime.toString())** there is another point in the code posted I don't see a reason for this function.

```
function () {
    var transform = function (data) {
      return $.param(data);
    };
```

as data you passed is already json

```
headers: {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8','Authorization': 'bearer'},
        transformRequest: transform,
        data: {

          "Name": "Michael Knott"
        }
```

you can remove transformRequest function in the backed also you will need to decode date.DateTime in the backend if you want to use it.